# LateX text rendering is not working with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying this simple code to display a mathematical expression that has  variables and their values but I got a big error. it seems that Latex does not work with Matplotlib.

See the picture

[image]

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc   
rc('text', usetex=True)

formula = r'm=\frac{{w}}{{g}} = \frac{{{0}}}{{{1}}}'.format(100,20)

plt.plot( [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], '.')
plt.text(1,1,r'\[{}\]'.format(formula),fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Here is the Error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" 

"C:/Users/Techno/PycharmProjects/try/MathExpression .py"

Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 227, in resize
    self.draw()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 12, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 433, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1475, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2607, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1192, in draw
    renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1130, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 922, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 309, in _get_layout
    ismath=ismath)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 232, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 501, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 365, in make_dvi
    texfile], tex)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 335, in _run_checked_subprocess
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 746, in callit
    func(*args)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 310, in idle_draw
    self.draw()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 12, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 433, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1475, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2607, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1192, in draw
    renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1130, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 922, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 309, in _get_layout
    ismath=ismath)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 232, in get_text_width_height_descent
    s, fontsize, renderer=self)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 501, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 365, in make_dvi
    texfile], tex)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 335, in _run_checked_subprocess
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running your code, and got this as a result:

[image]

Assuming this is the output you wanted, this means your code is written correctly, and your problem is likely with how Python is installed or configured in your system.

As your error message points out to something going wrong with Tkinter, there is a chance your graphics backend might the culprit, so that might be a good place to start investigating.

Over here, I run Python 3.6.5 64-bit from the Anaconda Distribution installation, and use Spyder as my IDE. In Spyder, I can change my graphics backend between Tkinter (amongst others) by going to `Tools` - `Preferences` - `IPython Console` - `Graphics` - `Graphics backend`. I tried running your code with my backend set to `Tkinter` and `automatic`, and it worked fine in both cases. I can see from your screenshot you're not using Spyder, but I hope this might help you find your own way through your system.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I am using PyCharm as IDE and I have PyQt5 included.I cannot find such option in pycharm

Comment: I ran the code using Python IDL and I got the same error

Comment: If I change rc('text', usetex=True) to "False" it will work but the output will be m=\frac{{w}}{{g}} = \frac{{{0}}}{{{1}}}

Comment: I'm afraid I am not familiar with PyCharm nor Python IDL, so I can't help you much there. I would suggest trying to google about how Tkinter works with PyCharm; maybe it needs some setup instructions before it starts working? Or try finding out how to change your graphics backend in PyCharm to something else, like Qt5.

Comment: Setting `usetex=False` will disable the Latex interpreter in Matplotlib, so your string will be parsed literally instead of interpreted as Latex commands - so yeah, in that case your should see exactly what you type popping up in your figure.

Comment: I just noticed your error message has the line `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` showing up twice. Perhaps Tkinter is not correctly installed and is missing some files? Googling for this specific error message might give you some other ideas to try and sort it out.

Comment: Thank you Fabio! I am inclined to say that is a setup problem for latex in matplotlib. I am trying to figure that out

Comment: That is another possibility. I will google for that specific error. will see

Comment: FileNotFoundError is a general error. I think my problem is specifically with usetex. I cannot find anything on google. let's wait and see other people suggestions

Comment: The Latex interpreter in Matplotlib is a bit fiddly sometimes, but at least in principle it should work "out of the box". However, it is possible your problem lies there. Good luck with sorting this out!